# Passing int to a method taking Integer as parameter?

Tags: java

Is it Ok to pass int to a method which is taking Integer as parameter.
Here is the code

```
public class PassingInt 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int a = -1;
        passIntToInteger(a);//Is this Ok?
    }

    private static void passIntToInteger(Integer a) 
    {
        System.out.println(a);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes it works. You could also do `passIntToInteger(new Integer(a));`

Comment: @Pphoenix Always use `valueOf` with the wrappers instead of `new`.

Comment: @chrylis: Thank you! Is there a reason to always do so, or is it just standard? :)

Comment: @Pphoenix It is actually a performance improvement (micro optimization). `valueOf` uses a cache for some "common" values, i.e. -127 to +127 internally - that means no object creation needs to happen for these values.

One general piece of advice to the OP is to generally avoid using auto-boxing and wrapped types when possible because it hides things that are happening and can bite back: You can get a `NullPointerException` when unboxing an `Integer` wrapper type that is `null` for example. The `equals` method also has some quirks when working with longs if I remember correctly.

Comment: @PermaFrost: Thank you, I did not know this before

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is OK, it will be auto-boxed.

The reverse is also OK and is called auto unboxing.

More info here:

[Autoboxing and Unboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is.

**Why?** Because of auto-boxing. Primitives are converted to an object of its corresponding *wrapper class*. From [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html):

> Autoboxing is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper classes. For example, converting an int to an Integer, a double to a Double, and so on.

In your case:

```
primitive type: int -> wrapper class: Integer
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in your example it would be [autoboxed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) (converted from an `int` primitive to an `Integer` object) -

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int a = -1;
    passIntToInteger(a); // <-- Auto Boxing
}

private static void passIntToInteger(Integer a) {
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

Java also has (auto-)unboxing (converting from an `Integer` object to an `int` primitive) -

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Integer a = -1;
    passIntegerToInt(a); // <-- Auto Un-Boxing
}

private static void passIntegerToInt(int a) {
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

This allows you to use primitives with collections, otherwise `List<Integer>` could not store `int`(s) (for example).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to do it, and it is possible to do also the opposite (from Integer to int)